# How to redirect (& show flash message) on CMS contact page when wrong captcha submitted

Tags: magento2, redirect, contact-form, captcha

I have added a Contact form in a CMS Contact page.

- added Layout Update XML section
- added `vendor/magento/module-contact/views/frontend/templates/contact.phtml`
- `vendor/magento/module-contact/controller/index/post.php`   commented the default redirect at line number 90 & added : `$this->_redirect('my_cms_contact.html');`

Although on Success captcha, form is submitted and flash message seen on same cms page.
However, when wrong captcha is submitted it redirects to `/Contact/index/index`

How to redirect to `my_cms_contact.html` & show flash message, when wrong captcha is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The captcha check for the contact us page is in this file - **vendor\magento\module-captcha\Observer\CheckContactUsFormObserver.php**

Also, you are making the changes directly in the core files which is not a recommended method. It would be better if you override it as it would be easier while performing the Magento version upgrade process.

Thank you.